# Domain redirection issue

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have two domains in my hosting account 1. example1.com 2. example2.com and also subdomain for example1.com i.e. dev.example1.com.

Now when I create a subdomain for example2.com i.e. dev.example2.com but it redirects to same dev.example1.com.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect is done,

from dev.example2.com to dev.example1.com

and you need to remove that.

DNS never does any redirects. It is the server which listens on that port performs the redirect.